# How do you calculate the distribution of frequencies in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

*I may just be using the wrong words to search for this question, cause it doesn't strike me as that complicated, but can't seem to find an answer on StackOverflow*

I have a list of strings;

```
 'Pelican Point',
 'Bridgetown',
 'Dunsborough',
 'Gelorup',
 'Ambergate',
 'Gelorup',
 'Yallingup Siding',
 'East Bunbury',
 ...
 'West Busselton',
 'Vasse',
 'Yallingup',
 'West Busselton',
 'Bunbury',
 'Collie',
 'Vasse',
 'Dunsborough',
 'Dunsborough',
 'Australind',
 'Busselton',
 'Busselton',
 'Abbey',
 'Dalyellup',
 'Quindalup'
```

And I would like to calculate;

- the number of entries in the list that are unique
- the number of entries that have between 5 and 2 entries
- the number with more than 5 entries in the list

Is this possible?

Comment: "the number of entries in the list that are unique" -- use set. "the number of entries that have between 5 and 2 entries" -- use Counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to build a frequency map, where the key is a unique string, and the value is the frequency.

After that, your queries become straightforward.

Comment: I do not have that much experience with Counter. Are you referring to using `Counter(lst)` and then manipulating the results of that? I believe that you get a list of lists, is it just then a case of looping through those lists?

Comment: `Counter` returns a dictionary, you loop through the dictionary and check if the value matches the frequencies you want

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want? You can change the code inside "if-elif" condition according to your need.

```
lst = [ 'Pelican Point', 'Bridgetown', 'Dunsborough', 'Gelorup','Ambergate', 'Gelorup', 'Yallingup Siding', 'East Bunbury', 'West Busselton', 'Vasse', 'Yallingup', 'West Busselton', 'Bunbury', 'Collie', 'Vasse', 'Dunsborough', 'Dunsborough', 'Australind', 'Busselton', 'Busselton', 'Abbey', 'Dalyellup', 'Quindalup']
 
S = set(lst)
 
for e in S:
    c=lst.count(e)
    if(c==1):
        print("count for ",e, " is ",c)
    elif(c>=2 or c<=5):
        print("count for ",e, " is ",c)
    else:
        print("count for ",e," is ",c)
```